# Eclipse keeps throwing Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Out of no where, my eclipse project has started throwing the following error. Not sure what am I doing wrong, I have searched this forums and tried googling the problem but to no avail. I can't figure out whether it's something to do with Eclipse or there's something wrong with my code. Let me know if I need to provide some more information. Please help!

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseUp(Widget.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseUp(Control.java:2569)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5635)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
```

Comment: Googling rarely leads to no avail. Start at the top: [StackOverflowError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)

Comment: have you ever by chance updated jvm, jre, os or something lately?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik 's suggestion is by far the best lead, but if you, Donshon, can offer some context to the problem (e.g. what is going on when you get the error) that would be helpful.

Comment: I have not updated any of those things Huseyin. I'm running webdriver test case; it runs the test, and once the test stops, I see this error popup. That is all I know. I really don't know what's causing the stack overflow and how do I know if indeed my code is causing it.

Comment: Bonus points for asking about a StackOverflowError on StackOverflow!